# Remove Bloat from Google Play Update list?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there a way to remove uninstallable apps from showing up on the `google play` updates list?  I don't mean uninstall them, that is not possible without root as I understand.  Just hiding them from the `update all` list would be nice.

Comment: Bloatware can be disabled safely. Also disabling them saves some space and memory if they are running in the background. You won't see them in update list after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know of to remove an app from the update process is to disable it - but then of course, you can't USE it at all.

I tend to disable a lot of built-in stuff (usually after the first time it decides to 'notify' me about something I don't care about). But as I said, that also means I can't use the apps in question.